# Typescript throws 'cannot invoke' while object for sure is function

Tags: typescript

Look at the following ts code snippet

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAtgrsAhgIwDYQDwEEA0AhAPigF4oBvAKCmtgUWAgC4oAKADymawEoSi8KAXwoVQkWIhDIIAWTppMuQiXJUa8JAwD8nVhy69iRLAG4oQkQGMA9gDsAzsGowQAMTi3LwAJZ2VAMw8vX1tsfAIWG1t-bwBzXSwoCDYGWwATeyg8KB0YSWk5JAUw5WYNFHQSghwoRAAnWLgYCFsnA0oaKHQncoYzNWpvf1YAcl6IEahvWygomNjeDs71OgYVObiAOnH+zsEk1HtoJeXaTWhSdgTDIg4BqGFO8fZufuEKIA

```
type mutable<A,B> = {
    mutate: (x : A) => B
}

type maybeMutable<A,B> = {
    mutate? : (x : A) => B; 
}

const  myFunction = function<A,B>(config : A extends B ? maybeMutable<A,B> : mutable<A,B>, argument : A){
    let mutate; 
    if ('mutate' in config) {
        mutate = config.mutate; 
    } else {
        mutate = (x : A) => x 
    }
    mutate(argument); 
}
```

Config might have property `mutate` or not, depends on A and B types. But for sure as we can see if it is presented it has to be **function**. Then code checks if `mutate` is in config, takes it or if not sets the default value. This default value is identity, **function** one more time. How then typescript deducts that mutate can be undefined and therefore throws and error `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the Problem is in the if, it doesn't eliminate the `undefined` possibility.

```
mutate?: (x : A) => A;
```

this includes `mutate: undefined` and `in` operator return `true` even if the object or its prototype chain is `undefined`

> A property may be present in an object but have value undefined. Therefore, x in obj is not the same as obj.x === undefined.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in#description

this will fix it:

```
type mutable<A,B> = {
    mutate: (x : A) => B
}

type maybeMutable<A,B> = {
    mutate?: (x : A) => A; 
}

const  myFunction = function<A,B>(config : A extends B ? maybeMutable<A,B> : mutable<A,B>, argument : A){
    let mutate; 
    if (typeof config['mutate'] === 'function') {
        mutate = config.mutate; 
    } else {
        mutate = (x : A) => x 
    }
    mutate(argument); 
}
```

Comment: Yep I know it is solvable that way. But it is not answer to question. How come if doesnt't eliminate undefined. Can you show me the case ?

Comment: @chilly_maximus when you use `in` it means it could exist but with `undefined` value, I added the explanation to the answer with a link.

Comment: Ohhh i forgot that { mutate : undefined } satisfies  { mutate? :(A) => A} which is a bit misleading. And this is real explanation, what you added is not that exactly. Anyways thx.

Comment: I thought the first line was enough to explain. sorry for giving the answer in parts (I kept editing and adding more), it is my first answer here.

Comment: yep Im sorry, i see my comment could be considered a bit unpolite against intention.